# unable to display session variables in a non-auth application

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store and retrieve form data in laravel session. My app is non-auth, meaning users are not required to register, hence no authentication. After attempting to store form data in session, when I try to output it says:

> "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Why do I get this? Does laravel session by default work only with authentication? If not, how do I solve this? Is there a workaround? View code below, thanks.

controller

`$request->session()->put('name', $request->input('name'));`

blade

```
<input type="text" value="{{session()->get('name')->name}}" id="name" name="name" />
```

Comment: Which of those two lines of code throws the error you've shown us? I guess the second one?

Comment: P.s. no, a session always exists in PHP, it doesn't require authentication to be present.

Comment: The second line. I'm using laravel

Comment: `I'm using laravel`...I know, you tagged it and mentioned it several times in the question already :-)

Comment: please add more context to the single line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the `->name` which is the issue...it looks like what you placed in the session was just a simple string containing a name, so why do you now expect that value to have a name property of its own?

You can just output the session value directly, without that extra bit:

```
value="{{session()->get('name')}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

just delete this `->name`

or you can use this :

```
value="{{ Session::get('name') }}"
```